# Linking a class when used inside another class

Tags: c++, class, import, linker

When I have a class I want to use somewhere else, such as `Secondaryfile.cpp`, I can import it fine into another file where I create a new class, as long as I do the class definition, etc inside the .cpp file, not the header file, otherwise I get linking errors. I have tried adding things like `extern "C"` in the `Secondaryfile.cpp` but to no avail. Looking at the errors, I also thought that pershaps I shouldn't use the namespace, however, that still results in the same error.

The reason why I am doing this is that I want to import a `Tertiaryfile` into `Mainfile` which has a function with the same name as a function in `Secondaryfile`, so I wanted to be able to refer them as, say, `Secondaryfile::add1()` and `Tertiaryfile::add1()` and avoid any issues with the same names that way - through the use of namespaces. I want to be able to declare the Mainfile class in its header file so that I can import it and use it in a different class down the line.

In the example below, running `g++ Mainfile2.cpp` compiles fine, however, `g++ Mainfile.cpp` doesn't, instead it results in the following error:

```
Mainfile.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile()'
Mainfile.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to 'Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile::getX()'
Mainfile.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to 'Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile(int)'
```

My code:
Mainfile.cpp

```
#include "Mainfile.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

Mainfile::Mainfile(char* name, Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile x)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->x = x;
}

Mainfile::getDoubleX(){
    return this->x.getX() * 2;
}

static Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile getObj(int num){
    return Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile(num);
}

int main(){

}
```

Mainfile.h

```
#ifndef MAINFILE_H
#define MAINFILE_H

namespace Secondaryfile{
    #include "Secondaryfile.h"
}

class Mainfile
{
 
public:
    char* name;
    Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile x;

    Mainfile(char*, Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile);

    int getDoubleX();
    static Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile getObj(int);

};

#endif
```

Mainfile2.cpp

```
namespace Secondaryfile{
    #include "Secondaryfile.h"
}
#include "Mainfile2.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

class Mainfile2{
    public:
        char* name;
        Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile x;

        Mainfile2(char* name, Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile x)
        {
            this->name = name;
            this->x = x;
        }

        getDoubleX(){
            return this->x.getX() * 2;
        }

        static Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile getObj(int num){
            return Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile(num);
        }
};

int main(){

}
```

Mainfile2.h

```
#ifndef MAINFILE2_H
#define MAINFILE2_H



int getDoubleX();
static Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile getObj(int);

#endif
```

Secondaryfile.cpp

```
#include "Secondaryfile.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile(int x)
{
    this->x = x;
}
Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile()
{
    this->x = 0;
}

int Secondaryfile::getX()
{
    return this->x;
}


int Secondaryfile::add1(int num)
{
    return num+1;
}

int main(){

}
```

Secondaryfile.h

```
#ifndef SECONDARYFILE_H
#define SECONDARYFILE_H

class Secondaryfile
{
 
public:
    int x;

    Secondaryfile();
    Secondaryfile(int);

    int getX();
    static int add1(int);

};

#endif
```

Comment: in Secondaryfile.cpp you forgot to include Secondaryfile.h in it's namespace. BTW : that is a bad style , a header should be autonomous.

Comment: I see what you mean. The reason why I am doing this is for linking scenarios where I import, say, a Thirdfile into Mainfile that has a function that shares the name with a function in Secondaryfile, say if Thirdfile also had an add1() method.

Comment: I am immediately thinking of function pointers or templates or virtualization. A  disgn issue.

Comment: There are also other problems. For example, in Mainfile.cpp you didn't specify the return type of `Mainfile::getDoubleX()`(I know it's been specified in the corresponding header file, but C++ demands it). In Mainfile2.h and Mainfile2.cpp you switch class declaration and member function definitions, which is also a bad practice.

Comment: @ViniciusAlmeida , do you mean that in Mainfile2 I took out the class declaration from the header file and put it in the cpp? If so, my point was that I want to have the class declaration inside the header file and then have the definitions inside the .cpp file, however, that causes the aforementioned error, where as using the way shown in Mainfile2.cpp doesn't. This difference is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: @engf-010 I will have a look at this as well, although from a quick glance I am not sure if these are applicable to what I want to do. I edited the question to add more details. Basically a function in `Thirdfile` might have a function with the same name as a function in `Secondaryfile`, but they might be used completely differently and do completely different things, just have the same name and arguments.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you're trying to solve your problem the wrong way. If I understand it correctly you're creating a contradiction.

Comment: @skacesmith check my answer and see if it clarifies what you're asking. I think you may be confusing some things, which is absolutely normal in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

1. In Mainfile.cpp you didn't specify the return type of Mainfile::getDoubleX()(it should be `int`)
2. You can only specify `static` member functions inside a class definition(in Mainfile.cpp, the function `getObj` has that qualifier). Also it should have a class scope, so the correct way of writing is `Secondaryfile Mainfile::getObj(int num)`
3. Doing `namespace Secondaryfile{ #include "Secondaryfile.h"}`. You shouldn't do this. Just `#include "Secondaryfile.h"` inside the source files is enough. You mention that you did this to prevent "linking errors", but that is probably because of the other problems in your code and in your project configuration.
4. You also didn't specify your compiler & IDE/cmake/makefile configs, which is **essential** for properly compiling and linking these header and source files.
5. Are you building a library or executable code? You include a `main()` function in your source files that doesn't do anything, which is also bad practice, because `main()` in C++ is an entry-point function, wich means that the compiler will look for it to create the starting point of the program<sup>1</sup>.

With these in mind, I tried to fix your code. See if this is what you had in mind:

Mainfile.cpp

```
//
// Created by vinicius on 21/10/2020.
//

#include "Mainfile.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

Mainfile::Mainfile(char* name, Secondaryfile x)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->x = x;
}

int Mainfile::getDoubleX(){
    return this->x.getX() * 2;
}

Secondaryfile Mainfile::getObj(int num){

    return Secondaryfile(num);
}

int main() {
    //Test code
    printf("Hello World!\n--------\n");
    Secondaryfile s = Secondaryfile();
    Mainfile f = Mainfile("myname", s);
    Secondaryfile myobj = f.getObj(12);
    printf("Value = %d", myobj.getX());
}
```

Mainfile.h

```
//
// Created by vinicius on 21/10/2020.
//

#ifndef MAINFILE_H
#define MAINFILE_H


#include "Secondaryfile.h"


class Mainfile
{

public:
    char* name;
    Secondaryfile x;

    Mainfile(char*, Secondaryfile);

    int getDoubleX();
    static Secondaryfile getObj(int);

};

#endif
```

Mainfile2.cpp

```
//
// Created by vinicius on 21/10/2020.
//


#include "Secondaryfile.h"

#include "Mainfile2.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

Secondaryfile Mainfile2::getObj(int num) {
    return Secondaryfile(num);
}

int Mainfile2::getDoubleX() {
    return this->x.getX() * 2;
}

Mainfile2::Mainfile2(char *name, Secondaryfile x) {
    this->name = name;
    this->x = x;
}
```

Mainfile2.h

```
//
// Created by vinicius on 21/10/2020.
//

#ifndef MAINFILE2_H
#define MAINFILE2_H





class Mainfile2{
public:
    char* name;
    Secondaryfile x;

    Mainfile2(char* name, Secondaryfile x);

    int getDoubleX();

    static Secondaryfile getObj(int num);
};

#endif
```

Secondaryfile.cpp

```
//
// Created by vinicius on 21/10/2020.
//

#include "Secondaryfile.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile(int x)
{
    this->x = x;
}

Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile()
{
    this->x = 0;
}

int Secondaryfile::getX()
{
    return this->x;
}

int Secondaryfile::add1(int num)
{
    return num+1;
}
```

Secondaryfile.h

```
//
// Created by vinicius on 21/10/2020.
//

#ifndef SECONDARYFILE_H
#define SECONDARYFILE_H

class Secondaryfile
{

public:
    int x;

    Secondaryfile();
    Secondaryfile(int);

    int getX();
    static int add1(int);

};

#endif
```

**And the CMakeLists.txt for the project(made in CLion)**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(secfile)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(.)

add_executable(secfile
        Mainfile.cpp
        Mainfile.h
        Mainfile2.cpp
        Mainfile2.h
        Secondaryfile.cpp
        Secondaryfile.h)
```

After building the project with cmake, you can run it. After doing that, it outputs the following lines:

```sh
Hello World!
--------
Value = 12
```

As expected.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function seems like as good a source as any for `main` being a program's entry point

Comment: Thanks for fixing the issues with my code - it is a lot clearer to me now. However, when I run your code, I get the same errors as before, except it complains about `undefined reference to 'Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile(int)' as opposed to 'Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile::Secondaryfile(int)', etc instead. To clarify, I am trying to compile the code in powershell running mingw g++ 8.1.0. Ultimately, I want to use Mainfile as a library, but I used the main classes to check the code. W.r.t point 3, how would you solve including two header files with functions that have the same name + arguments?

Comment: @skacesmith can you give me the build/linking flags and the commands you used? As you're using Windows, I'd have to verify what is going on. Also, it'd be great if you showed the full errors so that I can fix the problem more easily. **But** the 'undefined refence to [...]' suggests that you may not be linking your code properly.

Also, are you just compiling and linking manually with powershell and mingw? If so, it's really important to know which commands you are using.